# Theorem 1.34 Rudin's functional analysis (e)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

A question about the theorem:

> Suppose $p$ is a seminorm on a vector space $X$. Then
>
> (a) $p(0) = 0$
>
> (b) $\left|p(x) - p(y) \right| \leq p(x - y)$
>
> (c) $p(x) \geq 0$
>
> (d) $\left\{x : p(x) = 0 \right\}$ is a subspace of $X$
>
> (e) The set $B = \left\{x : p(x) < 1 \right\}$ is convex, balanced, absorbing, and $p = \mu_B$

The point $(e)$ is what my question is about, so I'll just write down the author's proof and then I'll ask the question

> If $x \in X$ and $s > p(x)$ then $p(s^{-1}x) = s^{-1}p(x) < 1$. This shows that $B$ is absorbing and also that $\mu_B(x) \leq s$. Hence $\mu_B \leq p$. But if $0 < t < p(x)$ then $p(t^{-1}x) \geq 1$ and so $t^{-1}x$ is not in $B$. This implies $p(x) \leq \mu_B(x)$ and completes the proof.

I was going through this proof last night and I'll give now my interpretation.

Suppose $x \in X$ and pick any arbitrary $s > 0$ such that $p(x) < s$, since $s$ is arbitrary but greater than $p(x)$ we can write $s = p(x) + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$. The author also states that $\mu_B(x) \leq s$, but this specifically follows from the definition of $\mu_B(x)$ to be precise. Hence we have the inequality
$$
\mu_B(x) < p(x) + \epsilon
$$
From this inequality it follows $\mu_B(x) \leq p(x)$, I've seen the proof many times on this website.

For the other part of the inequality I'm not sure what the author does, because to me

$$
\mu_B(x) = \inf \left\{ t > 0 : t^{-1}x \in B \right\} = \inf \left\{ t > 0 : p(t^{-1}x) < 1 \right\} = \inf \left\{ t > 0 : p(x) < t \right\}
$$

And from this definition it should follow that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$
p(x) < \mu_B(x) + \epsilon
$$

And as the former case it follows $p(x) \leq \mu_B(x)$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You could've probably guessed I was still writing...

Comment: Your argument looks fine but It's not really different from what Rudin does.

Comment: For some reason I find it confusing though.

Comment: $\inf \{t>0:\; p(x)<t\}= \inf (p(x),\infty)=p(x)$. What Rudin does is that he takes an element $t$ smaller than $p(x)$ and he uses the same calculation as you to show that $\mu_B(x)\geq t$.

Comment: Isn't then the $\inf$ a $\min$ actually then? and the proof can be simplified even more?

Comment: It's not a minimum. $p(x)$ isn't an element of your set. However, it *is* true that your line shows it in one fell swoop. It's just... not really different from Rudin's proof. Note that you still have to prove that $B$ is balanced and absorbing.

Comment: I'll read again through the proof to see similarities. The balanced and absorbing I don't think it's necessary for the very specific bit I've proved though, right?

Comment: No. I suppose not.

Comment: Ok, because that part is clear on its own.